# Minimum required tickets to get all lottery combinations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, lotteries

## Problem

Given a lottery system where $N$ balls are drawn at random (and not put back in the pool) and you can submit tickets containing between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ predictions, is there a minimum number of tickets $T$ that you can fill out to hit every possible combination of $n$ balls, or every combination of balls up to $n\leq N$?

For example in my country, there's a lottery that uses $45$ consecutively numbered balls of which $6$ are picked at random and then one more as the 'bonus' number. You can submit $6$ to $10$ predictions per ticket at varying costs. Depending on the number of correct predictions and whether you got the bonus ball right or not, you can win different amounts of money.

### Example

Let's say $N=5$, $x_{min} = 2$ and $x_{max}=3$. Two balls are drawn at random, as well as a bonus number.

#### Single number combinations

There are ${5 \choose 1} = 5$ combinations which you can make with $T=2$ tickets as $(1,2,3) \cup (4,5)$. You could also buy $T=3$ tickets, two containing two different pairs of numbers and one containing the remaining number and a duplicate number.

#### Two-number combinations

There are ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ combinations which using a greedy algorithm can be made with $T=4$ tickets as $(3,2,4) \cup (3,1,5) \cup (4,2,5) \cup (4,1,2)$ in no particular order. You could also buy $T=10$ tickets and fill in a pair each.

#### $n$-number combinations generalized?

For $n=1$ and $n=2$, above, the formula $T(N,x_{max},n)=\lceil {N \choose n} / {x_{max} \choose n} \rceil$ yields the number of tickets I'm thinking of. If this generally extends, then that would mean I would need $T(45,10,6)= \lceil {45 \choose 6} / {10 \choose 6} \rceil = 38 \, 786$ tickets. **But does it?**

#### Two-number and bonus number combinations

Since there are $10$ possible two-number combinations and $3$ remaining balls that can be the bonus number, that should be $30$ pair-bonus combinations right? I don't quite see how I can combine this idea with the general formula for $T$ above.

### My goal

Given all possible ticket combinations for each required number of correct guesses, I can use code to determine which is the cheapest and also how much money I would make (or probably lose). I'm also not sure if having $5$ correct numbers automatically also means that you got $4$, $3$, and $2$ right as well.

How can I extend this idea to higher values of $N$, $x_{min}$, $x_{max}$ and $n$?

Comment: In case you didn't find it already:
https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/
In that context, v is the number of balls in the pool, k is how many you select on a ticket, and t is the number you want to guarantee matching on at least one ticket.